# how to make a pair combination per each line

Tags: python

I have a .xls file with 4 rows but many columns. I saved it in tab delimited .txt file which looks like below 
The first column is important and each strings is separated by a `,`.
The example data can be found here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/92a95026f9869790f209dc9ce8f55a59

```
A,B                   A13   This is India
AFD,DNGS,SGDH         3TR   This is how it is
NHYG,QHD,lkd,uyete    TRD   Where to go
AFD,TTT               YTR   What to do
```

I want to combine pairs per each line and then keep the other lines repeated if we have more than one pair combination

This is what I am looking for

```
A       B        A13    This is India
AFD    DNGS      3TR    This is how it is
AFD    SGDH      3TR    This is how it is
DNGS   SGDH      3TR    This is how it is
NHYG    QHD      TRD    Where to go
NHYG    lkd      TRD    Where to go
NHYG    uyete    TRD    Where to go
QHD     lkd      TRD    Where to go
QHD     uyete    TRD    Where to go
lkd     uyete    TRD    Where to go
AFD     TTT      YTR    What to do
```

Lets call my first data `Data`

What I have tried is to read line by line

```
import itertools


lines = open("data.txt").readlines()
for line in lines:
    myrows = line.split(",") 
out_list = []
for i in range(1, len(myrows)+1):
    out_list.extend(itertools.combinations(lines, i))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got the right idea of using `itertools.combinations()` but you need to run it only in the first column elements, and not on the whole line.

Here is my solution:

```
import StringIO
import itertools

data = """"A,B     "    A13 This is India
"AFD,DNGS,SGDH   "  3TR This is how it is
"NHYG,QHD,lkd,uyete"    TRD Where to go
"AFD,TTT"   YTR What to do"""

for line in StringIO.StringIO(data):
    e1,e2 = line.split('\t', 1)  # extract the first part (e1) and the rest of the line (e2)
    es = e1.replace('"','').strip().split(',')  # remove extra "" and whitespace.
                                                # then split each element in a tuple
    for i in itertools.combinations(es,2):  # iterate over all combinations of 2 elements
        print '{}\t{}'.format('\t'.join(i),e2)
```

result:

```
A   B   A13 This is India

AFD DNGS    3TR This is how it is

AFD SGDH    3TR This is how it is

DNGS    SGDH    3TR This is how it is

NHYG    QHD TRD Where to go

NHYG    lkd TRD Where to go

NHYG    uyete   TRD Where to go

QHD lkd TRD Where to go

QHD uyete   TRD Where to go

lkd uyete   TRD Where to go

AFD TTT YTR What to do
```

**EDIT**

Here is the modified version.
Notice the `enumerate()` with `f.readlines()` which returns the index of the current line

```
import itertools

with open('data.txt') as f:
    header = f.readline()
    with open('result.txt','w') as w:
        w.write(header)
        for n,line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
            elems = line.split('\t')
            e0 = elems[0].split(',')
            e0 = [e.replace('"','').strip() for e in e0]
            for pairs in itertools.combinations(e0,2):
                w.write('{:d}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(n+1,'\t'.join(pairs),'\t'.join(elems[1:])))
```

Comment: I've modified my answer according to your comment

Comment: just open a file for writing and write in that file instead of stdout. See the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: looks like your data is not formatted as you described. Are you sure there are no blank lines or truncated line in your datafile?

Comment: your problem is that, contrary to your initial data.txt file, the columns are separated by repeated spaces instead of a tab. I've modified my code, but it will only work if there are 4 or more spaces to separate the columns. If possible, you should really try to generate your initial datafile with something unique, like a tab, or semi-colons, or something... In addition, I've added the writing to a result file (`result.txt`) part.

Comment: That's because I assumed your original datafile was already tab separated. Again, things would be much much simpler if you could have your initial datafile separated with a unique separator. Are you generating your datafile yourself and can you change the separator used?

Comment: if your data is indeed tab delimited, the final version that I posted should work.

Answer (score 0):

you_data.txt:

```
"Q92828, O60907, O75376"    15  NCOR complex        Human   MI:0004- affinity chromatography technologies | MI:0019- coimmunoprecipitation | MI:0069- mass spectrometry studies of complexes    12628926    "By using specific small interference RNAs (siRNAs), the authors demonstrate that HDAC3 is essential, whereas TBL1 and TBLR1 are functionally redundant but essential for repression by unliganded thyroid hormone receptor."
"O15143, O15144, O15145, P61158, P61160, P59998, O15511"    27  Arp2/3 protein complex      Human   MI:0027- cosedimentation | MI:0071- molecular sieving   9359840
"Q9UL46, Q06323"    30  PA28 complex     11S REG    Human   MI:0071- molecular sieving | MI:0226- ion exchange chromatography   9325261 "PA28 is a regulatory complex of the 20S proteasome. It acts as proteasome activator and stimulates cleavage after basic, acidic, and most hydrophobic residues in many peptides."
"P55036, P62333, O43242, P35998, P48556, P62191, Q13200, Q99460, O00232, P17980, P62195, O00487, P51665, Q15008, O75832, O00233"    32  PA700 complex    19S complex    Human   MI:0226- ion exchange chromatography | MI:0071- molecular sieving   9148964 "The proteasome is an essential component of the ATP-dependent proteolytic pathway in eukaryotic cells and is responsible for the degradation of most cellular proteins (for reviews see PMID:8811196 and PMID:10872471). It contains a barrel-shaped proteolytic core complex (the 20S proteasome), and is capped at one or both ends by regulatory complexes like the 19S complex (PMID:11812135), modulator (PMID:8621709), PA28 (PMID:9325261) and PA28gamma (PMID:9325261). Interferon-gamma (IFN-gamma) alters the peptide-degrading specificity of proteasomes and produces an immunoproteasome responsible for accelerated processing of nonself endogenous antigens by inducing the replacement of subunits Psmb5, Psmb6 and Psmb7 by Psmb8, Psmb9 and Psmb10, respectively."
```

code:

```
import itertools

with open('you_data.txt') as f:
    index = 1
    for line in f:
        split_line = line.split('"')
        key = split_line[1].strip().split(',', 2)
        value = split_line[2].strip().replace('\t',' ')

        for pair in itertools.combinations(key, 2):
            pair = [i.strip() for i in pair]
            print('{:<4}{:8}{:8}{:20}'.format(index,*pair, value))
        index += 1
```

out:

```
1   Q92828  O60907  15 NCOR complex  Human MI:0004- affinity chromatography technologies | MI:0019- coimmunoprecipitation | MI:0069- mass spectrometry studies of complexes 12628926
1   Q92828  O75376  15 NCOR complex  Human MI:0004- affinity chromatography technologies | MI:0019- coimmunoprecipitation | MI:0069- mass spectrometry studies of complexes 12628926
1   O60907  O75376  15 NCOR complex  Human MI:0004- affinity chromatography technologies | MI:0019- coimmunoprecipitation | MI:0069- mass spectrometry studies of complexes 12628926
2   O15143  O15144  27 Arp2/3 protein complex  Human MI:0027- cosedimentation | MI:0071- molecular sieving 9359840
2   O15143  O15145, P61158, P61160, P59998, O1551127 Arp2/3 protein complex  Human MI:0027- cosedimentation | MI:0071- molecular sieving 9359840
2   O15144  O15145, P61158, P61160, P59998, O1551127 Arp2/3 protein complex  Human MI:0027- cosedimentation | MI:0071- molecular sieving 9359840
3   Q9UL46  Q06323  30 PA28 complex  11S REG Human MI:0071- molecular sieving | MI:0226- ion exchange chromatography 9325261
4   P55036  P62333  32 PA700 complex  19S complex Human MI:0226- ion exchange chromatography | MI:0071- molecular sieving 9148964
4   P55036  O43242, P35998, P48556, P62191, Q13200, Q99460, O00232, P17980, P62195, O00487, P51665, Q15008, O75832, O0023332 PA700 complex  19S complex Human MI:0226- ion exchange chromatography | MI:0071- molecular sieving 9148964
4   P62333  O43242, P35998, P48556, P62191, Q13200, Q99460, O00232, P17980, P62195, O00487, P51665, Q15008, O75832, O0023332 PA700 complex  19S complex Human MI:0226- ion exchange chromatography | MI:0071- molecular sieving 9148964
```

Comment: @nik i have added it.

Comment: no the first column you add is numbers. it should be 1, 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 and 4 representing which lines those combinations are coming from

Comment: Thanks but still it does not work. I am getting this error, do you why File "test2.py", line 11
    print('{:<4}{:8}{:8}{:20}'.format(index,*pair, value))
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression

Comment: the code works fine to me, check whether the text file is same as mine, the idea is clear, you should know how to do it, just write your code.

Comment: @nik  now you can copy it, i tested it.

Comment: @ 宏杰李  the same error man $ python test2.py 
  File "test2.py", line 12
    print('{:<4}{:8}{:8}{:20}'.format(index,*pair, value))
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression

Comment: i have to off line, the data and code are posted in the answer, good luck

Comment: yes, the data is from link which you post on the comment, just copy my code and run it

Comment: can you just somehow save the results to .txt ? i will disactivate the printing function so it might solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of `flatmap`.

`import itertools
def tolist(s):
    return s.split(',')
def tostring(l):
    return [','.join([l[i],l[j]]) for i in range(len(l)) for j in range(len(l)) if i <j]
def tomult(ll):
    return map( lambda x: [x]+ll[1:] ,tostring(tolist(ll[0])))
def tofmap(lines):
    return list(itertools.chain(*map( lambda line: tomult(line) ,lines)))
a = [['c1,c2', '200', 'line one'], ['a,b,c', '100', 'this is good']]
b = tofmap(a)`